# Что делает программа математически

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
 
 
int t = 3; 
int n = 3;
int a[] = {-13, -30, -19, 4};
int x = a[n];
 
 
 
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){  
    x = x + a[j] * pow(t, n-j); 
}
cout << x << endl;
 

}
```

Всем привет, есть такая прога, вообщем она делает что то конкретное, но я не могу понять что если честно, кто осилит расшифровать и расписать математически или хоть как-то буду очень благодарен

Comment: Неэффективно (а по большому счету, и неверно из-за применения функции `double` для получения целочисленного результата) вычисляет значение полинома в точке `t`...

Comment: Тоесть вычисляет значение полинома в точке t, с коэффициентами из массива A?

Comment: @Harry, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаёт переменные `t` и `n` со значениями 3 и массив `a`, в котором есть значения `{-13, -30, -19, 4}`. Потом создаёт переменную `x`, значением которой становится элемент массива `a` с индексом `n`, то есть число 4. Затем выполняется цикл `for`. В его начале переменная `j` равна 0, цикл выполняется, пока она меньше `n`(3). С каждым повтором цикла переменная `j` увеличивается на 1. В теле цикла переменная `x` увеличивается на `a[j]`, умноженное на `t`(3) в степени `n-j`. То есть, разберём по повторам цикла:

1. `j=0, x=-347`
2. `j=1, x=-617`
3. `j=2, x=-674`

Далее цикл завершается, так как `j = 3` и условие `j<n` не выполняется.

Comment: int a[] - во вселенной C/C++ не может быть *списком* ни под каким соусом. Это все же массив.

Comment: @gbg, а как должно быть

Comment: Если Вам помог ответ, поставьте галочку)

Comment: Забавный разбор, в котором не сказано ни слова о том, что же *именно* вычисляется...